# How to correctly use the iter_download functionality for multi connection downloads in Telethon

Tags: telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, telethon

I've been trying to implement a multi threaded Telegram download client. For single downloads we can simply use the download_media functionality.

But telethon offers iter_download function, as per documenation it is used for streaming which also includes pausing and resuming functionality. We can use this to download a single file with multiple connections.

This is what I've scripted so far. No where to find any solid examples for multi connection download

```py
async def multi_downloader(file, total_size, part, offset, part_size):

    f = open('output.mkv.'+str(part), 'wb')
    size = 0

    global chunk_size
    limit = 10485760#closestInteger(part_size / chunk_size, 10485760)
    print(limit)
    print(part)
    async for chunk in client.iter_download(obj, offset = offset, limit = limit, chunk_size = chunk_size, request_size = chunk_size, file_size = total_size):
        f.write(chunk)
        f.flush()
        size += (len(chunk))
        if size >= (part_size):
            print("Part "+str(part)+" completed. "+str(part_size))
            break
    f.close()
```

The thing is it always throws the invalid limit error, if I change the offset for seeking. If the offset is zero then everything is fine.

> telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.LimitInvalidError: An invalid limit was
>   provided. See https://core.telegram.org/api/files#downloading-files
>   (caused by GetFileRequest)

Comment: You can try this code for multi connection download https://gist.github.com/painor/7e74de80ae0c819d3e9abcf9989a8dd6

Comment: "No where to find any solid examples for multi connection download". Note that `iter_download` is *not* for performing a download using multiple connections. It's simply a way to iterate over the chunks of a file (to effectively download it, using an iterator).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have already made somlething similar which you can find here https://gist.github.com/painor/7e74de80ae0c819d3e9abcf9989a8dd6 .
Code :

```
"""
> Based on parallel_file_transfer.py from mautrix-telegram, with permission to distribute under the MIT license
> Copyright (C) 2019 Tulir Asokan - https://github.com/tulir/mautrix-telegram
"""
import asyncio
import hashlib
import inspect
import logging
import os
from collections import defaultdict
from typing import Optional, List, AsyncGenerator, Union, Awaitable, DefaultDict, Tuple, BinaryIO

import math
from telethon import utils, helpers, TelegramClient
from telethon.crypto import AuthKey
from telethon.network import MTProtoSender
from telethon.tl.functions.auth import ExportAuthorizationRequest, ImportAuthorizationRequest
from telethon.tl.functions.upload import (GetFileRequest, SaveFilePartRequest,
                                          SaveBigFilePartRequest)
from telethon.tl.types import (Document, InputFileLocation, InputDocumentFileLocation,
                               InputPhotoFileLocation, InputPeerPhotoFileLocation, TypeInputFile,
                               InputFileBig, InputFile)

log: logging.Logger = logging.getLogger("telethon")
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.WARNING)
TypeLocation = Union[Document, InputDocumentFileLocation, InputPeerPhotoFileLocation,
                     InputFileLocation, InputPhotoFileLocation]


def stream_file(file_to_stream: BinaryIO, chunk_size=1024):
    while True:
        data_read = file_to_stream.read(chunk_size)
        if not data_read:
            break
        yield data_read


class DownloadSender:
    sender: MTProtoSender
    request: GetFileRequest
    remaining: int
    stride: int

    def __init__(self, sender: MTProtoSender, file: TypeLocation, offset: int, limit: int,
                 stride: int, count: int) -> None:
        self.sender = sender
        self.request = GetFileRequest(file, offset=offset, limit=limit)
        self.stride = stride
        self.remaining = count

    async def next(self) -> Optional[bytes]:
        if not self.remaining:
            return None
        result = await self.sender.send(self.request)
        self.remaining -= 1
        self.request.offset += self.stride
        return result.bytes

    def disconnect(self) -> Awaitable[None]:
        return self.sender.disconnect()


class UploadSender:
    sender: MTProtoSender
    request: Union[SaveFilePartRequest, SaveBigFilePartRequest]
    part_count: int
    stride: int
    previous: Optional[asyncio.Task]
    loop: asyncio.AbstractEventLoop

    def __init__(self, sender: MTProtoSender, file_id: int, part_count: int, big: bool, index: int,
                 stride: int, loop: asyncio.AbstractEventLoop) -> None:
        self.sender = sender
        self.part_count = part_count
        if big:
            self.request = SaveBigFilePartRequest(file_id, index, part_count, b"")
        else:
            self.request = SaveFilePartRequest(file_id, index, b"")
        self.stride = stride
        self.previous = None
        self.loop = loop

    async def next(self, data: bytes) -> None:
        if self.previous:
            await self.previous
        self.previous = self.loop.create_task(self._next(data))

    async def _next(self, data: bytes) -> None:
        self.request.bytes = data
        log.debug(f"Sending file part {self.request.file_part}/{self.part_count}"
                  f" with {len(data)} bytes")
        await self.sender.send(self.request)
        self.request.file_part += self.stride

    async def disconnect(self) -> None:
        if self.previous:
            await self.previous
        return await self.sender.disconnect()


class ParallelTransferrer:
    client: TelegramClient
    loop: asyncio.AbstractEventLoop
    dc_id: int
    senders: Optional[List[Union[DownloadSender, UploadSender]]]
    auth_key: AuthKey
    upload_ticker: int

    def __init__(self, client: TelegramClient, dc_id: Optional[int] = None) -> None:
        self.client = client
        self.loop = self.client.loop
        self.dc_id = dc_id or self.client.session.dc_id
        self.auth_key = (None if dc_id and self.client.session.dc_id != dc_id
                         else self.client.session.auth_key)
        self.senders = None
        self.upload_ticker = 0

    async def _cleanup(self) -> None:
        await asyncio.gather(*[sender.disconnect() for sender in self.senders])
        self.senders = None

    @staticmethod
    def _get_connection_count(file_size: int, max_count: int = 20,
                              full_size: int = 100 * 1024 * 1024) -> int:
        if file_size > full_size:
            return max_count
        return math.ceil((file_size / full_size) * max_count)

    async def _init_download(self, connections: int, file: TypeLocation, part_count: int,
                             part_size: int) -> None:
        minimum, remainder = divmod(part_count, connections)

        def get_part_count() -> int:
            nonlocal remainder
            if remainder > 0:
                remainder -= 1
                return minimum + 1
            return minimum

        # The first cross-DC sender will export+import the authorization, so we always create it
        # before creating any other senders.
        self.senders = [
            await self._create_download_sender(file, 0, part_size, connections * part_size,
                                               get_part_count()),
            *await asyncio.gather(
                *[self._create_download_sender(file, i, part_size, connections * part_size,
                                               get_part_count())
                  for i in range(1, connections)])
        ]

    async def _create_download_sender(self, file: TypeLocation, index: int, part_size: int,
                                      stride: int,
                                      part_count: int) -> DownloadSender:
        return DownloadSender(await self._create_sender(), file, index * part_size, part_size,
                              stride, part_count)

    async def _init_upload(self, connections: int, file_id: int, part_count: int, big: bool
                           ) -> None:
        self.senders = [
            await self._create_upload_sender(file_id, part_count, big, 0, connections),
            *await asyncio.gather(
                *[self._create_upload_sender(file_id, part_count, big, i, connections)
                  for i in range(1, connections)])
        ]

    async def _create_upload_sender(self, file_id: int, part_count: int, big: bool, index: int,
                                    stride: int) -> UploadSender:
        return UploadSender(await self._create_sender(), file_id, part_count, big, index, stride,
                            loop=self.loop)

    async def _create_sender(self) -> MTProtoSender:
        dc = await self.client._get_dc(self.dc_id)
        sender = MTProtoSender(self.auth_key, self.loop, loggers=self.client._log)
        await sender.connect(self.client._connection(dc.ip_address, dc.port, dc.id,
                                                     loop=self.loop, loggers=self.client._log,
                                                     proxy=self.client._proxy))
        if not self.auth_key:
            log.debug(f"Exporting auth to DC {self.dc_id}")
            auth = await self.client(ExportAuthorizationRequest(self.dc_id))
            req = self.client._init_with(ImportAuthorizationRequest(
                id=auth.id, bytes=auth.bytes
            ))
            await sender.send(req)
            self.auth_key = sender.auth_key
        return sender

    async def init_upload(self, file_id: int, file_size: int, part_size_kb: Optional[float] = None,
                          connection_count: Optional[int] = None) -> Tuple[int, int, bool]:
        connection_count = connection_count or self._get_connection_count(file_size)
        print("init_upload count is ", connection_count)
        part_size = (part_size_kb or utils.get_appropriated_part_size(file_size)) * 1024
        part_count = (file_size + part_size - 1) // part_size
        is_large = file_size > 10 * 1024 * 1024
        await self._init_upload(connection_count, file_id, part_count, is_large)
        return part_size, part_count, is_large

    async def upload(self, part: bytes) -> None:
        await self.senders[self.upload_ticker].next(part)
        self.upload_ticker = (self.upload_ticker + 1) % len(self.senders)

    async def finish_upload(self) -> None:
        await self._cleanup()

    async def download(self, file: TypeLocation, file_size: int,
                       part_size_kb: Optional[float] = None,
                       connection_count: Optional[int] = None) -> AsyncGenerator[bytes, None]:
        connection_count = connection_count or self._get_connection_count(file_size)
        print("download count is ", connection_count)

        part_size = (part_size_kb or utils.get_appropriated_part_size(file_size)) * 1024
        part_count = math.ceil(file_size / part_size)
        log.debug("Starting parallel download: "
                  f"{connection_count} {part_size} {part_count} {file!s}")
        await self._init_download(connection_count, file, part_count, part_size)

        part = 0
        while part < part_count:
            tasks = []
            for sender in self.senders:
                tasks.append(self.loop.create_task(sender.next()))
            for task in tasks:
                data = await task
                if not data:
                    break
                yield data
                part += 1
                log.debug(f"Part {part} downloaded")

        log.debug("Parallel download finished, cleaning up connections")
        await self._cleanup()


parallel_transfer_locks: DefaultDict[int, asyncio.Lock] = defaultdict(lambda: asyncio.Lock())


async def _internal_transfer_to_telegram(client: TelegramClient,
                                         response: BinaryIO,
                                         progress_callback: callable
                                         ) -> Tuple[TypeInputFile, int]:
    file_id = helpers.generate_random_long()
    file_size = os.path.getsize(response.name)

    hash_md5 = hashlib.md5()
    uploader = ParallelTransferrer(client)
    part_size, part_count, is_large = await uploader.init_upload(file_id, file_size)
    buffer = bytearray()
    for data in stream_file(response):
        if progress_callback:
            r = progress_callback(response.tell(), file_size)
            if inspect.isawaitable(r):
                await r
        if not is_large:
            hash_md5.update(data)
        if len(buffer) == 0 and len(data) == part_size:
            await uploader.upload(data)
            continue
        new_len = len(buffer) + len(data)
        if new_len >= part_size:
            cutoff = part_size - len(buffer)
            buffer.extend(data[:cutoff])
            await uploader.upload(bytes(buffer))
            buffer.clear()
            buffer.extend(data[cutoff:])
        else:
            buffer.extend(data)
    if len(buffer) > 0:
        await uploader.upload(bytes(buffer))
    await uploader.finish_upload()
    if is_large:
        return InputFileBig(file_id, part_count, "upload"), file_size
    else:
        return InputFile(file_id, part_count, "upload", hash_md5.hexdigest()), file_size


async def download_file(client: TelegramClient,
                                        location: TypeLocation,
                                        out: BinaryIO,
                                        progress_callback: callable = None
                                        ) -> BinaryIO:
    size = location.size
    dc_id, location = utils.get_input_location(location)
    # We lock the transfers because telegram has connection count limits
    downloader = ParallelTransferrer(client, dc_id)
    downloaded = downloader.download(location, size)
    async for x in downloaded:
        out.write(x)
        if progress_callback:
            r = progress_callback(out.tell(), size)
            if inspect.isawaitable(r):
                await r

    return out


async def upload_file(client: TelegramClient,
                                        file: BinaryIO,
                                        progress_callback: callable = None,

                                        ) -> TypeInputFile:
    res = (await _internal_transfer_to_telegram(client, file, progress_callback))[0]
    return res
```

usage :

to download files :

```
await download_file(client, msg.document, file, progress_callback=prog)
```

to upload files :

```
result = await parallel_transfer_to_telegram(client, file, progress_callback=prog)
await client.send_file(event.chat_id, file=result)
```

Known issues :

if you are using a bot account the DC ID might be messed up so you would need to do this just after calling .start() :

```
config = await client(functions.help.GetConfigRequest())
for option in config.dc_options:
    if option.ip_address == client.session.server_address:
        if client.session.dc_id != option.id:
            log.warning(f"Fixed DC ID in session from {client.session.dc_id} to {option.id}")
        client.session.set_dc(option.id, option.ip_address, option.port)
        client.session.save()
        break
```

Comment: Which python version to use to have this imported? I've tried python 3.5, 3.6, 3.8 everything is throwing syntax errors and stuffs.

Comment: any 3.6+ version should work. What's the full error you're having ?

Comment: Thanks for the code. I had to remove some erraneous codes like logging to get it working. I use python 3.8 now. And the code is working perfectly. It boosted my download speed upto 4 times the normal speed

Comment: @painor , Does your code support resume ?

Comment: No it does not, I don't think it's that hard to implement pause/resume/stop tho